# Ruby: two-dimensional arrays syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax, multidimensional-array

In Ruby, suppose we have a 2-dimensional array, why is this syntax fine:

```
array.each do |x|
  x.each do |y|
    puts y
  end
end
```

But this is not:

```
array.each{|x|.each{|y| puts y}}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This should be fine `array.each{|x| x.each{|y| puts y}}`

You forget to refer x first.

I.e. `.` is supposed to be left associate operator. If you have noting on the left side - this is an error.

Comment: Ah, indeed, maybe that's what he missed. I thought he was pondering on "why the syntax is not what I'd like it to be"? :)

Comment: Yeah, I just realized it after I've put my answer. Update it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your `do...end` blocks with `{...}` *carefully* you'll find that your second form works the same as your first. But `puts array` accomplishes the same thing as this whole double loop.

If I may offer some polite meta-advice, your two Ruby questions today seem like you maybe were asked to do some things in a language you don't know, and are frustrated. This is understandable. But the good news is that, compared to many other languages, Ruby is built on a very small number of pieces. If you spend a little time getting really familiar with Array and Hash, you'll find the going much smoother thereafter.